# IS there a way to disallow pull while there are uncommited changes in a subrepository?

Tags: mercurial

I've had a clean main repository but with uncommitted changes to a subrepository when I executed `hg pull --rebase`. I'm pretty sure that some time ago this was safe to do - it would immediately say that there are uncommitted changes, but after one of Mercurial updates it stopped checking subrepos when pulling the main repo. Is there any way to configure it so that it will check that all subrepos are clean before attempting pull to the main repo?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd have to script it into a `precommit` hook.  You could use the non-standard [onsub](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/OnsubExtension) extension to do it pretty quickly.